# Determine $\lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x_n$ with $x_n=2^n+3(-1)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

Question:

Determine $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $2^-$$^n$$x_n$ where $x_n$ = $2^n$ + $3(-1)^n$.

My working:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $2^-$$^n$$x_n$ = $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{2^n + 3(-1)^n}{2^n}$ = $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{3(-1)^n}{2^n}}{1}$ = 1

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3(-1)^n}{2^n} = 0$

I just feel I'm wrong somehow and would like for someone to agree with my working or explain why I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: Plz improve the title

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is OK. You have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}2^{-n}x_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n + 3(-1)^n}{2^n}=1+\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{3(-1)^n}{2^n}=1+0=1.
$$